# I want to pass values between fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

My situation is like this I have an activity home activity inside it there are three buttons to switch and a container. In each button click I have to replace the container with fragment say A,B,C. In these fragment have a common container which will be replaced by fragments X,Y.

so my problem is that when I want to display data inside say X fragment I want to know which is the parent fragment A or B or C. So how to make this problem solved

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you are a simple record data, you can remember a variable only when switch(replase) fragment